# AOT build leaves component templates in the final bundle

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-aot

After doing AOT build with webpack bundle inludes every component template two times making the bundle much bigger than needed as templates are included as strings which cannot be minified by UglifyJS.

I expect component templates to be excluded as strings. They are already handled by ngc and built into compiled components.

Anyone know why its happening or how to fix it?

Comment: I have no idea because I use angular CLI that does that right for me, but if you want to know why your build does something, you should post your build.

Answer (score 1):

I found that 'angular2-template-loader' webpack loader generated unneeded component templates in the AOT bundle.

Solution is to remove this loader when using AOT.